# Ionic 2 button in slider

Tags: mobile, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a basic slider in Ionic 2

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    <button (click)="doAction()">Click me</button>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

And in my ts file

```
doAction() {
  console.log("clicked");
}
```

Clicking the button does nothing. If I place the button anywhere outside the slider it works fine. Is the slider capturing the click event somehow?

Comment: I test your code and its fine!

Comment: @aminarghavani I just tested it again and it now works SOMETIMES. It's so odd! Outside the slider it works fine. Inside the slider it only works maybe once every 10 clicks. Very strange

Comment: @aminarghavani I've just discovered that if I swipe to the right the button works fine, but if I swipe to the left it doesn't. I have the slider set to loop by the way. Could you confirm whether that is the case for you? Thanks

Comment: Put your complete code here if possible?

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect your button , you will see (.button-inner).
So, changing it to outer it would make it work fine.